# Is there any RPG with a tech tree or crafting system?

Tags: game-recommendation

Are there any RPGs with a tech tree like Age of Empires or Civilization?  What about a crafting system?

For the tech tree, I want a tree-based mechanic for technology in a sweeping scale world building game.

Comment: Just FYI, in case you're confused like some new members are, this site isn't about video games - so I hope you're asking for a recommendation about _tabletop_ RPGs played with pen and paper and dice, or you're in the wrong place and looking for [gaming.se]! If you are after tabletop RPGs, what do you mean by a tech tree? Lots of tabletop games feature a structured tree-shaped progression system, but do you mean for the entire party or for individuals, and what kind of content are you looking for in it? For a crafting system (which lots of RPGs have), what features do you want?

Comment: A single character often doesn't really live long enough to truly experience advances in technology, which makes rules for actual advancement to be unlikely to appear in an RPG... if you're playing a single character. What kind of a game are you looking for? There might be games out there where you play the leaders of an advancing society that might very well have rules to this kind of thing.

Comment: Umm... this is probably on topic.  There may not be many RPGs with fleshed out Civ-like tech trees for societies, but that makes this a *good* question, not a bad one.  The question would be a horrible question if it was about video games, because the answer would be a massive list.  This should be tagged game-rec though.

Comment: OP, more information on what exactly you want would be helpful though.  Are you just looking for a tree-based mechanic? Are you looking just for sweeping scale world building in an RPG?  Are you looking for specifically a tree-based mechanic for technology in a sweeping scale world building game?

Comment: Please don't edit this to make it on topic just to do it. If the OP clarifies it's really for here, fine. But it serves no one to turn it into an on topic question the poster's not asking and doesn't care about.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Entirely possible, I hadn't considered that! Nonetheless, it's not *clear* that this is the case (and in any event we'd need more detail), so closed it should stay.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I think it would be the last one.  "tree-based mechanic for technology in s a sweeping scale world building game."  I have edited the question.

Comment: @johnny Okay. What about the crafting system? What are you looking for there?

Comment: And you are looking for a tabletop RPG not a computer game right?